# Call value into string from a server

Tags: android, spinner

I want to access a list of strings from a server.
Below is my code. When I select first spinner value in second spinner display fetch 
from server. When I select any value of spinner in out put I want value send by server 
please explain.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Library11 extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Spinner sp;
    Spinner sp1;
    Spinner sp2;
    Spinner sp3;
    Spinner sp4;
    Spinner sp5;
    String[] menu;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp2;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp3;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp4;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp5;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp6;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp7;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_library11);
        sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
        sp1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        menu= new String[]{"Select Subject","Engineering Physics-I","Engineering Chemistry","Engineering", "Mathematics-I","Communicative English","Fundamentals of Computer Programming"
    };
}
```

In the upper section, spinner one calls the value and then I use an array adapter for the second spinner, but here I want to access web server value. If it is possible to edit this or if I have to change something, please let me know.

```
String[] Author=new String[]{"Author"}; 
      String[] Physics=new String[]{"H.c. Jain(320)"};
       String[] Chemistry=new String[]{"Yasmin Ali(180)"};
       String[] Maths=new String[]{"Gokhru(200)"};
       String[] English=new String[]{"Jain & Jain(200)"};
       String[] Mechanics=new String[]{"Jaz(320)"};
       String[] Programming=new String[]{"Jaz(320)"};
       adp= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu);
       adp1= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Author);
       adp2= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Physics);
        adp3= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Chemistry);
       adp4=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Maths);
       adp5=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,English);
       adp6=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Mechanics);
       adp7=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Programming);

       sp.setAdapter(adp);

      sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
       }
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        menu[0]="Select Subject";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected the book & Author available", 1500).show();
            if(sp.getSelectedItemPosition()==0)
                sp1.setAdapter(adp1);
            if(sp.getSelectedItemPosition()==1){
                sp1.setAdapter(adp2);
                }
            if(sp.getSelectedItemPosition()==2){
                sp1.setAdapter(adp3);
                }
            if(sp.getSelectedItemPosition()==3){
                sp1.setAdapter(adp4);
                }
            if(sp.getSelectedItemPosition()==4){
                sp1.setAdapter(adp5);
                }
            if(sp.getSelectedItemPosition()==5){
                sp1.setAdapter(adp6);
                }
            if(sp.getSelectedItemPosition()==5){
                sp1.setAdapter(adp7);
                }
            }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    //  sp.setAdapter(adp3);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code. It's kind of similar to yours. My code retrieves Facebook friends from the Facebook API and adds them to a `spinner`.

```
public class Friends extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        try{
            String fql = "SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE is_app_user  AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

            parameters.putString("query", fql);
            parameters.putString("method", "fql.query");
            parameters.putString("access_token",  fb.getAccessToken());
            String Response = fb.request(parameters);
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(Response);
            list = new ArrayList<String[][]>();
            String[][] friendsToList;
            SpinnerList = new ArrayList<String>();
            String TempToSpinnerList=new String();
            for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
                friendsToList = new String[1][2];
                friendsToList[0][0] = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("uid");
                friendsToList[0][1] = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                TempToSpinnerList= friendsToList[0][1];
                list.add(i,friendsToList);
                SpinnerList.add(TempToSpinnerList);
            }
            return null;
        }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v)
    {
        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Iterator<String> it = SpinnerList.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String ve = (String) it.next();
            dataAdapter.add(ve);
        }
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        Log.e("Hh","Done");
    }
}
```

You can use a similar AsyncTask connected to your server socket to get the data required.